# HAL with Spring Hateoas and Mvc (without Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, hal

I´m using spring mvc and hateoas to build a restful api. Previously, I used spring boot with hateoas and the server rendered the responses as I expected. Now, that I'm not using spring boot, the server does not render the responses properly. From my research, I found some folks talking about a solution that involves the configuration of message converters. So, in addition to the annotation @EnableHypermediaSupport, what is needed to set the media type HAL without spring boot?

ApiConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = { HypermediaType.HAL })
public class ApiConfiguration {
}
```

ApiInitializer.java:

```
public class ApiInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { ApiConfiguration.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
  }
```

}

pom.xml:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.19.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

AdaptationRestController.java:

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(Adaptation.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/adaptations")
public class AdaptationRestController {

    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.xpto-adaptation+json")
    public ResponseEntity<AdaptationResource> getAdaptation(@PathVariable("id") String adaptationId) {
        Adaptation adaptation = adaptationGateway.getAdaptation(adaptationId);
        AdaptationResource adaptationResource = adaptationResourceAssembler.toResource(adaptation);

        return new ResponseEntity<AdaptationResource>(adaptationResource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

AdaptationResource.java:

```
public class AdaptationResource extends Resource<Adaptation> {

    public AdaptationResource(Adaptation adaptation) {
        super(adaptation);
    }

}
```

What I get:

```
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://xpto.com"
    }
],
...
```

What is supposed:

```
"_links": {
    "self": {"href": "http://xpto.com"}
},
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by not enough? what do you expect and what you get? spring boot add dependencies like jackson which may does the magic.

Comment: I edited my question to include what I get and what I expect. I already tried to include the following dependencies and the problem persists: json-path, jackson-databind ,  jackson-core and jackson-annotations

Comment: Curious, what is the reason for not wanting to use Spring Boot?

Comment: Initially I was using spring boot but one of the reasons for dropping it were the difficulties I encounter in using @ControllerAdvice for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Data JPA for data access, you could enable its web support declaratively by adding `EnableSpringDataWebSupport`. This would register bunch of `ArgumentResolvers` for `Controller` methods. Put simply, you can add `PagedResourcesAssembler` argument to your methods and use its `toResource` method for converting `Page`ed entities to resources, like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity getAll(PagedResourcesAssembler ass) {
        Page<User> users = userRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10));
        PagedResources pagedResources = ass.toResource(users, assembler);

        return ok(pagedResources);
    }
```

with this json output:

```
{"_embedded":{...},"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/users"}},"page":{...}}
```

Comment: I´m not using data access on my project. Anyway, I tried adding the annotation EnableSpringDataWebSupport and the json remained the same.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also facing this issue after migrating from Spring Boot to Spring.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to make your model extends **org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport**

```
public class MyModelClass extends ResourceSupport
```

then

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myresource", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<MyModelClass>> getAll() {
Iterable<MyModelClass> all= repository.findAll();
for(MyModelClass p : all) {
p.add(linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class).getAll()).slash(p.getId()).withSelfRel());
}
return new ResponseEntity<>(all, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I´m doing that. I edited the question to include the controller and the resource entity.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i am using `EntityLinks` to build links, without extending my Pojo from any framework dependent classes.

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(ProjectServiceResponse.class) 
public class ProjectController {
  @Autowired
  private org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks entityLinks;

  public HttpEntity<Resource<ProjectServiceResponse>> get(...){
    Resource resource = new Resource<ProjectServiceResponse>(response);
    resource.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(ProjectServiceResponse.class).withSelfRel());
    return new ResponseEntity<Resource<ProjectServiceResponse>>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Response:

```
"_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/project"
}
```

In my above code `ProjectServiceResponse.class` is POJO.

you can refer complete project on [github](https://github.com/lovababu/SpringBootExample)

Comment: The idea is the same. I just implemented an additional class that extends Resource<...> to avoid all the verbosity of Generics and implemented an assembler class that build the resource with links from the domain entity. You are using Spring Boot. I have no problems when I use Spring Boot in my code. When I remove Spring Boot, the transformation to HAL does not work.